# AWS :Script at specified location: scripts/start_server run as user root failed with exit code 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

While Deploying getting the error "The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems."
[image]